# Ghostscript runs smoothly on local PC before and after Pyinstaller, but when running the exe file on other PC always shows ghostscript not installed

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pyinstaller, ghostscript, python-camelot

So I was using Pyinstaller to make an exe file that can work without various dependencies for my colleague. One library I was using is camelot. The code runs without Ghostscript issues before I make the exe file with Pyinstaller (running the code in VS Code), and no error after I complied the file with Pyinstaller.

Then I tried to run the exe file on my colleague's PC and it continued saying that ghostscript not installed.

Same error happened even after I manually installed ghostscript and added both its bin and lib to PATH.

I don't understand. Pyinstaller should include every dependency before making the exe file and there shouldn't be any other problems after. Or it's ghostscript's problem?

Comment: Pyinstaller should include every **Python** dependency. I don't believe it could include external programs like Ghostscript. They must be installed separately.

Comment: It certainly isn't a Ghostscript problem. As @phd says, you need to install non-Python dependencies yourself, so you'll need to install Ghostscript, since it isn't written in Python. You can always check to see if Ghostscript is installed by running 'gs' at the command shell.

Comment: Sorry guys, but I said I already installed Ghostscript and added both its bin and lib to PATH and same error popped up again. That's my question.